# Pass a variable into nested query

Tags: mysql

Assume user table has 200 records.

The query below works for a certain **worker_id** 
For example worker_id 2738:

```
SELECT SUM(something) AS T_BOIN
FROM (
SELECT SUM(A.boin) AS something 
FROM hall A JOIN user B ON A.who=B.id 
WHERE B.worker_id = 2738
ORDER BY total_per_user DESC LIMIT 10
) AS mastertbl
```

I want to execute the above query for 200 seperate worker_ids like this:

```
SELECT @TT:=BK.worker_id AS TID, 
 (SELECT SUM(something) AS T_BOIN
 FROM (
  SELECT SUM(A.boin) AS something
  FROM hall A
  JOIN user B ON A.who=B.id
  WHERE B.worker_id = @TT
  ORDER BY total_per_user DESC 
  LIMIT 10) AS mastertbl
 ) AS TEAM
FROM user BK
INNER JOIN (SELECT @TT :=0) AS WESS
GROUP BY TID
```

But @tt is out of scope.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you...

```
SELECT worker_id, SUM(something) AS T_BOIN
FROM (
  SELECT b.worker_id, SUM(A.boin) AS something, if(@wid = b.worker_id, @cnt:=@cnt+1, @cnt:=1 AND @wid := b.worker_id) cnt
  FROM hall A
  JOIN user B ON A.who=B.id 
  ORDER BY b.worker_id, total_per_user DESC
) AS mastertbl
WHERE mastertbl.cnt <= 10
GROUP BY worker_id;
```